# How to recognise letters with UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

Is there a way to give UIGestureRecognizer a shape (a series of co ords) which it can use to trigger an action when the user draws the shape with his fingers? I'm thinking of letter shapes, but it could be anything.

EDIT:

I found this https://github.com/chrismiles/CMUnistrokeGestureRecognizer which will probably do what I want.

Comment: you should create an instance of the `UIGestureRecognizer`, and you can define the custom gesture in there, and using it you will be able to recognise anything literally, which you just can define.

Comment: Hey @cannyboy are you able to run the code in which you had got here in the gihub ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately implementing custom gesture recognisers isn't as simple as providing a `UIGestureRecognizer` with a shape or series of points. You have to subclass `UIGestureRecognizer` and write code that tracks the user's interaction through `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `touchesMoved:withEvent:` etc. Then,  based on line lengths and angles etc. of the gesture the user draws you determine whether it successfully matched what you were expecting and fire the `UIGestureRecognizer` callback.

This results in inherent complications as users are not very precise when squiggling gestures with their fingers. You would have to design your gestures with a tolerance as to what was recognised; too strict and it will be useless, too generic and it will report too many false positives.

I suspect that if you were attempting to recognise a large quantity of gestures, like the letters of the alphabet for instance, instead of implementing 26 different gesture recognisers you would be better off writing a generic one that recorded the user's input once and checked whether it matched a selection of gesture definitions you have stored somewhere. Then implement a custom callback that tells the handler which gesture it matched.

The very reputable '[Beginning iOS Development: Exploring the iOS SDK](http://www.apress.com/9781430245124)' series from Apress dedicate a small portion of a chapter to implementing a custom gesture recogniser. The accompanying source code can be downloaded from the official Apress website [here](http://www.apress.com/9781430236054) (Source Code/Downloads tab at the bottom).
See pages 627-632 in chapter 17: 'Taps, Touches, and Gestures'.

The [Gesture Recognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW2) chapter of Apple's [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH1-SW1) contains a 'Creating a Custom Gesture Recognizer' section that also has relevant information and examples.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I edited my question with a solution I found.

Comment: @cannyboy No problem, I'm sorry I couldn't suggest any high quality third party libraries to accomplish what you want (like the project you found). I've never had to implement anymore than a few simple custom gesture recognisers. I hope your solution works out for you, thanks for posting it.

Comment: As a note, the link you posted to the book was for a pirated ebook, so I've removed that.